# Going back to master branch and revert files

Tags: git, gitlab

Besides the branch `master` i have created another branch `develop`.

Now i have made some commits to `develop` and did a `pull origin develop` on the test-server instead of `pull origin master`.

Is it possible to get back to my `master` branch on the test-server and revert all files that i fetched in `pull origin develop` ?

I have already tried `git checkout master` and then `git pull origin master`, but it says:

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

and no fles from `develop` have been reverted.

```
$ git branch -av
  develop                        3e22f0c some-commit
* master                         3e22f0c [ahead 6] some-commit
  remotes/origin/HEAD            -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop         3e22f0c some-commit
  remotes/origin/master          86198f0 some-commit
```

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/273172/how-do-i-reset-master-to-origin-master/273199) is what worked for me when I had a similar problem.

Comment: `git checkout -B master origin/master` did it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `git pull origin <branch_name>` on a branch different from the one you currently check out, git will execute two operations: it will 1.) fetch the latest version of  from remote and 2.) merge it into the branch you have checked out.

In essence, this just leads to an extra commit that you want to revoke. There are a couple of options to do this:

1.) do a hard reset to the previous commit: `git reset --hard HEAD~¹`
2.) do a hard reset to the HEAD of your remote tracking branch `git reset origin/master`
3.) the same hard reset can be done with `git checkout -B master origin/master`
4.) revert the merge commit with `git revert -m 1 HEAD` (not a great option since it leads to two extra commits in your log)